# App Engine missing in Cloud Console

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-console

I have an old project (~1.5 years) that I want to start working on again.  It shows up in the project list in the developers console. I am wanting to add an App Engine component to the project, but this item is missing from the categories on the left, i.e. under **Compute** I only have "Compute Engine, Container Engine, Click to Deploy".

Another project that I started more recently also lists "App Engine" before "Compute Engine".

I am thinking that this is an older project that hasn't been updated completely on the back-end. When I recently (this week) went into the project, a popup asked me to accept a Project ID(i.e. random-word-####). Previously the project didn't have a Project ID, just a Project Number.

I tried to follow a process that I saw for linking an App Engine to an existing Cloud Project, but creating a new App Engine project automatically creates a new Cloud Project.

Is there a way to be able to create a new App Engine program under an older Cloud Project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding App Engine support to existing projects that were created outside of Developers Console is currently not possible. This is something we are working on, and I expect it to be added in the coming months.